# php curl_exec doesn't outupt anything

Tags: php, curl

I've got aproblem with my php cUrl.
It doesn't output anything so whenever i run this it will return: "didnt work"

```
$curl = curl_init();
$url = "https://www.google.com/";
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($result === FALSE) {
   print "didnt work!";
} else {
   print "worked!";
}
```

I've searched countless tutorials etc. and no sulotion worked for me.
Thx for the help in advance :)

Comment: you need to setup properly for `https` , both the environment (CA certs), and the curl call itself.

Comment: Thank you sooo much o.o

Comment: Unable to reproduce - works (just some relative image links should be fixed to be absolute paths). Have you tried to output http response header ? Try adding option `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);` and see the exact output with `echo "<xmp>$result</xmp>";`. What do you see ?